# What is the Visual Studio registry settings to make IDE tabs MRU-sorted?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I read a VS tip for VS 2008 some time ago that specified a registry setting that could be used to make document tabs in the IDE MRU-ordered, e.g. whenever you switched to the document it would automatically jump to the leftmost position.

Now, try as I might, I cannot find the article. 
Does anyone know the setting/the article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was on Sara Ford's blog [here](http://saraford.net/2008/10/09/did-you-know-you-can-keep-recently-used-files-from-falling-off-the-file-tab-channel-331/).  Specifically, the registry setting for VS2008 is:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0]
UseMRUDocOrdering = 1 (REG_DWORD)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/). This allows for a ton of customizations in the IDE.